# How Collection subclasses contents are printed,when collection is not overriding toString()?

Tags: java, tostring

```
Collection col=new ArrayList();
col.add("a");
col.add("b");
System.out.println(col);
```

When `toString()` method is not overriden in `java.util.collection` package then how come printing a collection object prints all its content?

Comment: Do you know about polymorphism?

Comment: ArrayList extends `java.util.AbstractCollection` which does override the `toString()` method

Comment: Remember its class isn't actually `Collection` its still an `ArrayList`

Comment: public class ArrayList<E> extends AbstractList<E>
        implements List<E>, RandomAccess, Cloneable, java.io.Serializable{............}                             @SyamS its not extending java.util.AbstractCollection

Comment: Arralist extends abstractlist which extends abstract collection. `public abstract class AbstractList<E> extends AbstractCollection<E> implements List<E>`

Comment: Yes. That is what I'm saying. If a class or one of the super class has a `toString()` method it'll gets executed. If none of them has then `toString()` method in `Object` class will be executed.

Answer (score 6):

From AbstractCollection which ArrayList extends...

```
/**
 * Returns a string representation of this collection.  The string
 * representation consists of a list of the collection's elements in the
 * order they are returned by its iterator, enclosed in square brackets
 * (<tt>"[]"</tt>).  Adjacent elements are separated by the characters
 * <tt>", "</tt> (comma and space).  Elements are converted to strings as
 * by {@link String#valueOf(Object)}.
 *
 * @return a string representation of this collection
 */
public String toString() {
    Iterator<E> it = iterator();
    if (! it.hasNext())
        return "[]";

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append('[');
    for (;;) {
        E e = it.next();
        sb.append(e == this ? "(this Collection)" : e);
        if (! it.hasNext())
            return sb.append(']').toString();
        sb.append(',').append(' ');
    }
}
```